# Adding git repo to Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

It seems that out of the box, `Jenkins` does not support `git`:

[image]

How can i add `git` to `Jenkins` please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install a plugin to use git in `Jenkins`. In the main page, click on `manage jenkins` and than `magage plugins`. Click on available tab and search for `git`.